# How to listen database connection event on jboss when db reconnects success?

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

The problem is, while we are doing some things, the db connection is lost. Then, the jboss is trying to reconnect:

```
Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:888)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1553)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:207)
... 16 more
```

I want to listen on db connection event when the connection is re-established; because I need to re-do some jobs...
Investigating with google, but I don't find any solution. Everyone, can you help me?